# Using Mono packages from badgerports, getting an exception on runtime

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono

I'm trying to port over a .NET application that was written in C#, into linux.
The compatibility test using the MoMa tool says the application is compatible.
I compiled the code using Visual Studio 2010, and copied the resulting .exe file over to my Ubuntu VM (running 10.04 LTS).

I had installed mono with the badgerport sources (from http://badgerports.org/lucid.html).  I see that I have the 4.0 libraries in the /usr/lib/mono directory:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/mono
total 52
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 2012-08-27 07:15 2.0
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 2012-08-27 07:15 3.5
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 12288 2012-08-27 07:15 4.0
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2012-08-27 07:14 compat-2.0
drwxr-xr-x 145 root root 12288 2012-08-27 07:15 gac
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 2012-08-27 07:15 mono-configuration-crypto
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2012-08-27 07:15 monodoc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 2012-08-27 07:15 xbuild
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 2012-08-27 07:15 xbuild-frameworks
```

When I look at the man page for mono, I see at hte top Mono 2.5.
And mono -V returns the following.

```
user@ubuntu:~$ mono -V
Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-1~dhx1~lucid1)
Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc, Xamarin, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
TLS:           __thread
SIGSEGV:       altstack
Notifications: epoll
Architecture:  x86
Disabled:      none
Misc:          softdebug 
LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
```

Here is the output when I try to run the application.

```
user@ubuntu:~$ mono MyApplication.exe 

Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
at MyApplication.ConsoleRunner..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MyApplication.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
at MyApplication.ConsoleRunner..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MyApplication.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Any insights into what is going on, and what I can do to fix it?  Unfortunately I am confined to using Ubuntu 10.04 due to other development constraints.

Comment: If I were you i would try to build the project on mono develop on Ubuntu, and check on debugger whats going wrong..

Comment: You need to compile the program using at the very least the Windows Mono compiler.  As for the reason for the downvote this shows a lack of research on your part.

Comment: @IDontKnowPopePersonally - Thanks, I thought this was originally a mono setup or configuration problem so I didn't think to debug it.  I'll give that a shot to see what's going on.

Comment: @Ramhound - Nope, I've never used mono so I didn't even know where to begin with this.  I'm trying to learn.  Lack of helpfulness on your part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely *not* have to compile using Mono compiler, at least not by design. Try running with `MONO_LOG_LEVEL="debug" mono your_software.exe`, you will see attempts to find assembly and other, possibly useful, informations. And put it here ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, didn't know there was a log level.  I worked through the issue I had previously and the app is now running.  The problem was that I hadn't referenced some of the dlls properly.  On the other hand the SerialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold isn't supported in Mono so I'll have to handle Serial Input a little differetly.  Output works great though.  Thanks for the help though, I'd upvote if I had the reputation.